# tensorflow: Classifier: errorjava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Label number 1000 mismatch the shape on axis 1

Tags: android, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to do codelab of google on tensorflow.

[link to the google codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/recognize-flowers-with-tensorflow-on-android/)

it worked with the given *.tflite model of tensorflow.
but when trying to it with the custom build model of tflite it gives the following exception.

errorjava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Label number 1000 mismatch the shape on axis 1

can't find out the reason behind it.

Comment: Any progress here? I'm also facing this issue, and if you could share an answer, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. I have solved it by changing the labels.txt but didn't change the labels_without_background.txt.

The file labels_without_background.txt is the model use. Change it to your own label content.

You can see ClassifierQuantizedEfficientNet.java line58

```
> protected String getLabelPath() { return "labels_without_background.txt";}
```